# Generated input element with jquery and for function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This code to generate input element with jquery and the amount of element is calculated from times of two other input

```
$('#generate').click(function () {
var a = parseInt($('#row').val());
var b = parseInt($('#col').val());
var val = a*b;

var innerhtml = '';
for (var i = 0; i < val; i++) {
    innerhtml += "<input type='text' class='seat' id='" + (i + 1) + "' name='" + (i + 1) + "'>";
        for (var j = 0; j = a; j++) {
            innerhtml += "xxx";
        }
}
$('#textbox_div').html(innerhtml);
});
```

If i fill input #row and #col with 2 & 3, jquery will generated 6 element (2*3 = 6).
The output will be like this:

- Input 1
- Input 2
- Input 3
- Input 4
- Input 5
- Input 6

From the code above how to get output like this (Add xxx every after 2 row):

- Input 1
- Input 2
- xxx
- Input 3
- Input 4
- xxx
- Input 5
- Input 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
var a = 4; //parseInt($('#row').val());
var b = 2; //parseInt($('#col').val());
var val = a*b;

var innerhtml = '';
for (var i = 0; i < val; i++) {
    innerhtml += "<input type='text' class='seat' id='" + (i + 1) + "' name='" + (i + 1) + "'>";
    if (i < val - 1 && i % 2 === 1 ) {
        innerhtml += "xxx";
    }
}
$('#textbox_div').html(innerhtml);
```

As you can see I replaced your inner `for` loop to an `if` statement. It tests two things:

1. Don't put "xxx" to the end
2. The remainder of i/2 is 1

Demo jsfiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/FHXYs/2).
Demo with variable xxx step size [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/FHXYs/3/)

Comment: How about put "xxx" every 'var a' times?

Comment: I added a second fiddle to demonstrate that (variable `n`).